# Can a laptop battery be charged with ~30 series connected lemons?

Tags: battery-charging

You arbitrarily identify 2 relatively distanced spots on a lemon or potato and place a piece of copper wire in one spot and a ferrous nail into another spot. So some type of passive electrolysis will occur between the different metals. Suppose 1 medium-sized lemon or potato would produce ~1 V. You connect a bunch of such lemons, e.g. 30, in series, so you get ~30 V with 2 end terminals for connection to the load.
A regular laptop (HP 250 G6, for example) uses 19.5 V and 2.31 A, for example. Is it possible to connect such a lemon or potato power pack to a laptop battery and charge it? Or connect it to an AC/DC adapter connected to a laptop and thus charge the battery?

Comment: Have you measured the current available from your lemon stack? It is likely milliamps rather than amps.

Comment: It might charge very slowly, if the charging circuitry even accepts a load that's so badly current-limited.

Comment: Nope. I suppose this amp rating is for a working laptop. But if you charge a battery removed from the laptop, having miliamps from such lemon stack may just make the charging very slow?

Comment: Ok, very slow. But is it possible to place a static magnet on each lemon between the "electrodes" to make the movement of charges more organized?

Comment: 30 lemons, each producing 7mW for 24 hours (hard data on longevity of lemon batteries is hard to come by, this was the average of the few values I could find), would equal 5Wh.  The battery for a HP 250 G6 is 41Wh, so the 30 lemons would charge your laptop less than 1/8th of the way.  The discrepancy between this and the 6435 lemons in my answer is that the power required by the charger is more than is required to charge the battery in 24 hours.  Magnets won't do anything.

Comment: @Asetofchara Why do you think a magnet would do anything? It won't.

Comment: Maybe not a static, but a changing magnetic field could induce electric field and thus increase the current.

Comment: That's just a generator.

Comment: @vir lemons or potatos are not essential in specifics. I was getting ~1V from a plastic 200ml container with just water and sea salt and 2 such electrodes. Didn't measure current though. Just thought to transfer voltage from one batched container to another.

Comment: Or if more charges are needed to increase current than maybe more such electrode pairs could be placed in one lemon more densely to increase charge separation or more easily dissociating compounds added.

Comment: You could also change the iron and copper to lead and lead dioxide, swap the citric acid for sulfuric acid, and get 2.05V per cell.

Comment: @vir Yet with 30 lemons, a step-up transformer may potentially amplify this voltage and produce the neseccary current?

Comment: @Asetofchara: A transformer that steps up voltage will necessarily step down current.  A transformer can't create power from nowhere.

Comment: The point is that when you remove the battery, it doesn't do any work.

Comment: Please try it, document the results with measurements and report back.

Comment: There is another side of this. When the lemons no longer produce current what happens when the battery is still supplying voltage potential and the possibility of current to the lemons? The end result is a dead battery but what happens from charging to dead?

Answer (score 6):

A quick look on Wikipedia shows that a typical lemon will produce 1mA at 0.7V, or 7mW.  On a power basis alone, you would need 6435 lemons to equal the 45W that your laptop takes, not to mention the inevitable losses from the thousands of feet of wire connecting them together.

Comment: It's a pithy ...

Comment: I remember when Microchip tried to showcase their extremely low power microcontrollers by showing one running on a lemon. But it took at least 2 or 3, and it didn't last long.

Answer (score 2):

I found a link to a document by Renesas showing one of their MCUs running on the power from a single lemon:

https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/fly/whitepaper-1-lemon-powered-design?language=en

(Could not post image)

Answer (score 1):

My rough calculation using (unconfirmed Googled values) of 0.9V @ 0.25mA  or 0.7V at 1mA for a single lemon indicates you'd need around 30-90 lemons just to cover the ~1mA self-discharge of a ~20V Li-ion battery pack.

Hopefully life gives you an aweful lot of lemons if you want to actually charge the battery in a reasonable period of time.

And, of course at least one of the electrodes (zinc, typically) will be consumed in the 'lemon' battery.